# Entity Relationship Diagram Relationship between attributes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship

On my Chen diagram I have the Entity **Orders** which has the attributes: ID (primary key), ProductID, UserID, Quantity.

Now its getting the ProductID from when an order is purchased from the products table. So even though ProductID is an attribute of Orders, it's also an attribute of Products and many other entities on my diagram. How do I best represent this? Is it just as simple as in each Entity that uses the ProductID, I just put it there?

Comment: Are you confusing Chen diagrams with other so-called ER diagrams?  ProductID shouldn't be an attribute of Orders, it should be an attribute of Products and there should be a relationship between Product and Order entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Foreign key you can set relation between Entities .
My advice to you is first design tables and diagrams in sql server and then generate it to Entity Framework model. The simple way

This method called **Entity framework Database first**. The below links is microsoft msdn that helped me to end up my project. It's so useful document

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx